# Decomposing dates in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have been handed a requirement to enable business users to decompose a subset of date fields on a number of entities into string fields of year, month and day. Dynamics does not appear to have functionality to do this out of the box.

I would like to add it using calculated fields. The most appealing approach is to extend the list of [functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832103.aspx) available in calculated field expressions and expose one that calls [DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) or one of its friends. Unable to find documentation on the topic. Is this possible or supported?

In the absence of such a possibility, does anyone have good ideas of how to accomplish the decomposition? Other than writing a plugin...

---

*Note: I am aware that this is probably a bad idea due to date culture and presentation issues. But this is what the business wants and only choice is to develop the least worst solution.*

Comment: A download to Excel and doing the decomposition there is not an option I presume?

Comment: Correct. Excel route is not an option. It has to be automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at installing [Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools](https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools).

Once installed, you could create a workflow to run when any of your given DateTime fields update.

The workflow would involve a step which uses the "[Date Functions](https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools/blob/master/docs/DateFunctions.md)" step from the workflow tools. This step accepts two DateTime parameters (though optionally one) and calculates several output values, namely for your scenario:

- Year
- Month
- Day

Your final workflow step would set your decomposed entity fields equal to one of the three output values as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, it would appear the list of functions for calculated fields cannot be extended. Calculated field expressions "compile" into scalar-valued functions that are called by the calculated column expression on the underlying table. Those SQL functions are generated by code in `Microsoft.Crm.CalculatedField.dll`.

Without diving into too many details, the list of expression functions appears to be tied to the `Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Activities.ExpressionOperator` enumeration in `Microsoft.Crm.dll`. Being tied to that enumeration indicates the list is hard coded.

For those who need a solution that does not include all of the extras contained in [Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools](https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools), here is one:

```
public class DateFormatter : CodeActivity
{
    public const string DEFAULT_LOCALE = "en-us";

    [Input("Date")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<DateTime> Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Input("Locale")]
    [Default(DEFAULT_LOCALE)]
    public InArgument<string> Locale
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Input("Format")]
    public InArgument<string> Format
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Output("Formatted Date")]
    public OutArgument<string> DateAsString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        DateTime? date = this.Date.Get(context);
        string locale = this.Locale.Get(context);
        string format = this.Format.Get(context);

        if (date.HasValue == false)
        {
            this.DateAsString.Set(context, null);
            return;
        }

        DateTime value = date.Value;
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(locale ?? DEFAULT_LOCALE);
        string dateAsString = (format == null) ? value.ToString(culture) : value.ToString(format, culture);
        this.DateAsString.Set(context, dateAsString);
    }
}
```